# Dart buit-in example from dart.dev

Tags: dart

As a beginner I tried to understand basics and I followed the dart website, here is a chapter about but-in.

[Buit-in chapter](https://dart.dev/language/built-in-types)

There are some example of using it:

````
// String -> int
var one = int.parse('1');
assert(one == 1);

// String -> double
var onePointOne = double.parse('1.1');
assert(onePointOne == 1.1);

// int -> String
String oneAsString = 1.toString();
assert(oneAsString == '1');

// double -> String
String piAsString = 3.14159.toStringAsFixed(2);
assert(piAsString == '3.14');```
````

Then I tried the latest one, I expected to ave no issue, here is the dart code I implemented below:

```
void main() {
        String piAsString = 3.14159.toStringAsFixed(2);
        assert(piAsString == '3.14');
}
```

When I run the code I got that issue:

> 3.14
> Unhandled exception:
> FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)
> 3.14
> ^

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Are you sure you have saved the file you are working on? The error looks like it could be related to some previous work you have been doing since the error does not really make sense in the context of your last example you have posted.

Comment: @julemand101, you're right, I forgot to save the file , now, no more issue with that code.

But I wrote and save:

void main() {
 
  String piAsString = 3.14159.toStringAsFixed(2);
  print(piAsString);// 3.14
  print(piAsString.runtimeType); // Strinng
  int valpi = int.parse(piAsString); // Responsible of the issue
  print(valpi);
  
}

Build and run and got :

3.14
String
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)
3.14
^

Comment: The problem with the code in your latest comment is that you are using `int.parse` instead of `double valpi = double.parse(piAsString);`. The problem is that your number are a floating point number and not an integer so when you ask the integer parser to parse the number, it fails.

Comment: Hi, thanks I study double ... but I completely forgot the difference between int and double, also the error message is not enough clear about.

Thanks again, for you time and the answer.